# constexpr address of base class

Tags: c++, base-class, constexpr, c++14

Using clang 3.4 (trunk), is there any way to calculate the displacement of a base class with a constant expression?

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B { int b; };

struct C: A, B {};

// cannot access base class of null pointer:
constexpr auto c_b_address = /*(size_t)*/ &(B&) *(C*)nullptr;
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of: _why would you do that?_

Comment: I'm working on a reflective model to allow navigating between members and base classes. is preferable to construct the metadata at compile time.

Comment: The displacement is a number in units of *bytes*. This requires subtracting both pointers as `char*`, which in turn requires a `reinterpret_cast`. If there's not some trick like `offsetof`, then I doubt you can pull it off.

Comment: @dyp the question is, why can't `offsetof` be done at compile-time?

Comment: @TemplateRex I don't think it's forbidden to be used at compile-time, it's just not guaranteed to be usable in a constant expression. The underlying issue is probably pointer arithmetics in constant expressions (see e.g. [CWG 1313](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1313)).

Comment: @dyp `gcc` and `clang` provide a little documented way to use things like `reinterpret_cast` in a constexpr. I discuss it in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398102/constexpr-and-initialization-of-a-static-const-void-pointer-with-reinterpret-cas/24400015#24400015). I don't see how you do the pointer math without invoking undefined behavior though.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes,** it's possible to calculate the displacement of a base class with a constant expression, but it's not at all portable.  You can use a little-known but [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp-3262) gcc extension that is also supported by clang.  It involves the use of `__builtin_constant_p` when used with the operator `?:`:

```
#define CB (&(B&)*(C*)nullptr)
constexpr auto c_b_address = __builtin_constant_p CB ? CB : CB;
```

Note that I've just used the macro CB to make it clear what was happening.  This could also, of course, be done by repeating the expression multiple times.  Incidentally, I first learned of this trick [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369606/constexpr-pointer-value) which contains useful background information.

The basic problem, as you probably already understand, is that neither a `reinterpret_cast` nor the equivalent C-style cast are allowed in `constexpr` expressions.  Curiously, the C-style cast (as above) is accepted, but a `reinterpret_cast` (which would generate no code) is not.  I also experimented with the obscure but seemingly appropriate `->*` operator but with mixed results:

```
#define CB1 (&(B&)*(C*)nullptr)
#define CB2 (&((reinterpret_cast<C*>(nullptr))->*(&C::b)))
#define CB3 (&(((C*)(nullptr))->*(&C::b)))
#define CB4 (&(B&)*reinterpret_cast<C*>(nullptr))
#define CB CB1
```

Results with g++ 4.8.3 and clang++ 3.4:

```
     g++             clang++
--- ------------    --------
CB1  OK              OK
CB2  compile error   compile error
CB3  OK              compiles but gives answer = 0
CB4  compile error   compile error
```

On my 64-bit machine running Linux, only `CB1` yields the correct answer of 4 with both compilers.  With gcc, both `CB1` and `CB2` work with or without `__builtin_constant_p`.  Using clang the only version that worked was `CB1` with `__builtin_constant_p`.

### Why should we believe this is intentional behavior?

As @ShafikYaghmour quite reasonably asks in a comment, "do you have a gcc or clang reference that says that they support this behavior?"  I'm going to broaden this to ask "what documentation exists that indicates this is intentional and not just an odd side effect?"  After all, if someone is actually going to use this, it would be nice to have some indication that it might actually continue to exist in the future.  This section attempts to address that concern.

For clang, the reference is [the source code itself](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ExprConstant_8cpp_source.html) in which a comment in the `VisitConditionalOperator` function which says:

```
// If the condition (ignoring parens) is a __builtin_constant_p call,
// the result is a constant expression if it can be folded without
// side-effects. This is an important GNU extension. See GCC PR38377
// for discussion.
```

This in turn, points to gcc's Bugzilla [bug 38377](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38377) which discusses this issue.  Specifically, in 2008 this bug was reported as "__builtin_constant_p(t) ? t : 1 is not considered a constant integer expression".  In the discussion, it's noted that for the conditional operator (`?:`),

> Yes, this is a (documented) special case required to be compatible with 
>   existing GNU C code.

And further,

> If you get this wrong for C then GCC will fail to bootstrap, as it's part of the GNU C semantics GCC relies on when being built with GCC.

Given that, it seems that the behavior is both specific and deliberate, and because gcc itself relies on it, probably a fairly stable behavior.

Still, all the usual caveats about using non-standard implementation details apply.  If you can perform this at runtime instead, it becomes acceptable to both gcc and clang:

```
ptrdiff_t cb = (char *)(&(B&)*(C*)nullptr) - (char *)nullptr;
```

Comment: +1, so it's non-standard andone shouldn't rely on it

Comment: "but the equivalent `reinterpret_cast` is not" -- I may be missing something, but aren't your C-style casts all equivalent to `static_cast`s?

Comment: @hvd: A `reinterpret_cast<C*>` just says, "trust me, compiler, this thing is really a `C*`, while a `static_cast` might actually invoke a user-defined or compiler-supplied conversion.  For this purpose, we want a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @Edward The rules for a C-style cast say that `(C*)x` means `static_cast<C*>(x)`, when that is valid (and even some times when it is not valid). So if `static_cast<C*>(x)` is valid, then `(C*)x` automatically is *not* equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<C*>(x)`, even in the rare case where `reinterpret_cast` is what you really want. And all of your conversions seem valid with `static_cast`.

Comment: @hvd: I see what you mean. Semantically I was going *from* `reinterpret_cast` to C-style, but you've expressed the conversion from the other direction.  I'll try to clarify that in my answer.

Comment: So when you say non-portable you really mean that this code invokes undefined behavior but may have well defined implementation defined results.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: If we understand that "undefined behavior" in this context means "undefined by the standard", then yes, that's a fair rephrasing.

Comment: @Edward I am curious, so do you have a `gcc` or `clang` reference that says that they support this behavior? This is basically offsetof hack which we can find evidence that it should work but debatable that it is actually supported.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: That's a very reasonable question.  I've updated my answer to attempt to address it.

Comment: to clarify I was referring to your use of `nullptr` here `&(B&)*(C*)nullptr`.