# Meaning of valid pointer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In the comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24398173/3002139) answer I stumbled about a discussion about the meaning of "valid pointer". Since I think that that is interesting in general:

What is a "valid pointer" in C++?

In particular:

Is `reinterpret_cast<const void*>(0x1)` a valid pointer?

Comment: Perhaps it might help if you reread the other post with compile-time constant propagation in mind, which is one of the big problems that `constexpr` was designed to solve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Standard places implementations into two general categories:

- Those with strict pointer safety
- Those with relaxed pointer safety

Your expression definitely is not a safely-derived pointer, so it's invalid in the first.

Quote from 3.7.4.3:

> An implementation may have *relaxed pointer safety*, in which case the validity of a pointer value does not depend on whether it is a safely-derived pointer value.  Alternatively,  an implementation may have *strict pointer safety*, in which case a pointer value referring to an object with dynamic storage duration that is not a safely-derived pointer value is an invalid pointer value unless the referenced complete object has previously been declared reachable (20.7.4).  [ Note:  the effect of using an invalid pointer value (including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined, see 3.7.4.2.  This is true even if the unsafely-derived pointer value might compare equal to some safely-derived pointer value.  — end note ] It is implementation defined whether an implementation has relaxed or strict pointer safety.

For implementations with relaxed safety, it doesn't matter how the pointer value is gotten, just that (3.9.2):

> A valid value of an object pointer type represents either the address of a byte in memory (1.7) or a null pointer.

Is `0x1` a valid memory address on your system?  Well, for some embedded systems it is.  For most OSes using virtual memory, the page beginning at zero is reserved as invalid.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right kind of reference. The "pointer safety" stuff is about opaquely supporting garbage collection, I think. My point about valid pointers is a consequence of the various "Expression" rules, e.g. what you can add, subtract and dereference.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Pointer values can be valid, and still lead to undefined behavior if used in certain ways (example: passing the address of an automatic variable to `::operator delete()`)

Comment: Regarding your edit: This is getting a bit confused, because the question is in reference to `constexpr` pointers, and `constexpr` explicitly forbids expressions that would have undefined behaviour (e.g. out-of-bound array access). So while you might be able to use a platform-defined, reinterpreted address, it's not allowed as a constant expression... (though I suppose we know that).

Comment: @KerrekSB: What undefined behavior?  It's properly aligned, and it hasn't been dereferenced.

Comment: It's not a legal constant expression by virtue of the fact that `reinterpret_cast` is used, not because of any undefined behavior.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough - I was trying to say that you cannot prove statically that it's *not* undefined behaviour. You couldn't even prove that `p + 0` is not undefined behaviour. It *might* be OK, but you cannot know (from within the language). If it's OK on your platform, that's external information that you're bringing in.