# What will be the output of this program

Tags: c

This was actually asked in my college quiz in C language.

```
a. Value is not printed

b. 100

c. Address of the variable n;

d. Garbage value
```

I marked option **'c'** as createarray returns the address of n

But on the answer key and many people are arguing that it will option d.

So can you help in understanding this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *createarray();
int main() 
{
    int *a;
    a=createarray();
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0; 
}
int * createarray() 
{
    int *p,n=100; 
    p=&n;
    return p; 
}
```

Comment: The value is "garbage" in the sense that the pointer does not point to a valid object because `n` no longer exists after the function exits.

Comment: `a` is pointer. To show the value in `a`, the correct code is `printf("%p\n", (void *)a);` Using `%d` for a pointer is not valid, and the result will be garbage on many systems.

Comment: Program has undefined behavior, so there is no correct answer. All of the proposed ones could happen. Or something else.

Comment: @Mat Can you please Help me understand it more.
The program has undefined behavior because the address it's pointing to is no longer exist?
Or any other reason

Comment: @DeepanshuSingh: the format string doesn't match the argument type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504148/what-can-happen-if-printf-is-called-with-a-wrong-format-string

Comment: And if it did match the format string, the answer would still be garbage because there cannot be the address of the variable `n` given that the variable `n` [no longer exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/11683).

Comment: @4386427 it is valid to print that value, and it might even be a [valid pointer value in itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24398510/11683), but option `c` calls for *address of variable `n`*, not for *a valid pointer value*. There is no variable `n` anymore.

Comment: @GSerg oh - I see - I misunderstood your comment. So I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `printf` format string is wrong: `%d` is used to print integers and you are giving it a pointer, so the program has undefined behavior. So as written, none of the 4 options are correct (although all are possible except `c` which is meaningless). If the `printf` format is fixed to use `%p`, then the question is what is `a`, can its value be accessed, and what does the standard say will be the result.

`a` points to an object that's reached the end of its lifetime, so its value is indeterminate. An indeterminate value may be an unspecified value or a trap representation. In the former case some pointer value will be output, and in the latter case it's undefined behavior as before.

See the C standard (here I'm quoting from the C99 standard):

- §7.9.6.1.9 (on `fprintf`, but it also applies to `printf`): "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."
- §6.2.4.2 "The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to reaches the end of its lifetime."
- §3.17.2.1 "indeterminate value: either an unspecified value or a trap representation"

So, the least wrong answer to the question is `d`, but you have to fix the code, and then assume that your compiler produces code that never generates trap representations, and understand "garbage" to mean "unspecified".