# Determine `constexpr` execution - during compilation or at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Is there a way to achieve different behaviour of a `constexpr` function in the compilation phase and at runtime?

Consider the following example (using a theoretical feature from `D: static if`):

```
constexpr int pow( int base , int exp ) noexcept
{
    static if( std::evaluated_during_translation() ) {
        auto result = 1;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < exp ; i++ )
            result *= base;
        return result;
    } else { // std::evaluated_during_runtime()
        return std::pow( base , exp );
    }
}
```

If not, is there a way to restrict `constexpr` to be compile-time only?

Comment: If you use it in a [conext where a constant expression is required then it should be evaluated at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25891133/1708801)

Comment: You might have luck with GCC-intrinsic `__builtin_constant_p`...

Comment: @Deduplicator not a very well documented feature, at least last time I looked but I put everything I could find on it in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24400015/1708801).

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936549/constexpr-overloading is there any movement on constexpr overloading going on?

Comment: I believe that std::pow will become constexpr before the rules for constexpr are changed to allow what you are asking for.

Comment: `std::pow` was just an example, there might be other usecases where compiletime and runtime algorithms might differ

Comment: [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24785fe2f3eb6798) (*proof-of-concept*) that I just wrote might be of interest, accepted by *gcc* and *msvc*, though *clang* has a [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15481) related to the magic used; let me know and I'll provide it as an answer to your question.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp so `noexcept( constexpr-func )` can determine if something is evaluates during translation/runtime - nice! It took me a while. An answer would be great since you already did alot of work

Comment: @Serthy `noexcept(expr)` will yield `true` if *expr* is a *constant-expression*, so the "magic" involved is simply checking whether the arguments involved can appear in a *constant-expression* - and if so we will call the `constexpr` version of our function.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp that is a neat trick, let me know if you provide an answer based on that.

Comment: This post seems like a good idea but I'm thinking about whether it can be adopted for functions with parameters... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290363/13080413 or in C++17, don't declare you function `noexcept`, and then do `noexcept(func(arg))` -- it'll be true if a constexpr function NOT marked noexcept was executed at compile time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to C++20, this wasn't possible. C++20 then added [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) which is exactly for this use case:

```
constexpr int pow(int base, int exp) noexcept
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    {
        auto result = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < exp; i++)
            result *= base;

        return result;
    } 
    else
    {
        return std::pow(base, exp);
    }
}
```

Note that the `if` statement itself is **not** `constexpr`. If it were, the whole else arm would be removed from the function and it would always run the if arm, no matter if at compile time or runtime. With a normal if statement, you basically get two functions. One that runs at compile time:

```
constexpr int pow(int base, int exp) noexcept
{
    auto result = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < exp; i++)
        result *= base;

    return result;
}
```

and one that gets compiled an runs at runtime:

```
constexpr int pow(int base, int exp) noexcept
{
    return std::pow(base, exp);
}
```

The compiler can safely remove the if arm because it can prove that it isn't reachable at runtime. Pretty neat.

Comment: Good answer Timo. You might want to make it explicit that "prior to C++20 this wasn't possible".

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no such way.

Sorry.

[N3583 is a paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3583.pdf) proposing changes to allow what you are asking for.

Comment: Just saw this [Scott Meyers talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE) where he also says that one have to use two different functions.

Comment: This paper is a good answer, unfortunately we have to wait a few years until (if ever) it gets implemented. A type trait would be easy to implement for compiler-writers and would have a minimal impact on the standard.

Comment: Do you know the status of this proposal?

Comment: @Serthy No.  I spent a few minutes, and didn't see it.  isocpp sometimes links to "current proposal status" lists, you can look there.

Comment: Update: There seem to be different approaches for this now [this blog post](http://saadahmad.ca/detecting-evaluation-context-inside-constexpr-functions/) and [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0595r0.html)

Comment: Has this situation changed with C++17?

Comment: @einpok no: google constexpr operator, which is the last time I heard about this.