# Check if a function call can be resolved in compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, constexpr

Basically, I need to check if a function call can be resolved in compile-time or not and based on that, generate one `constexpr` function for compile-time use and one non-`constexpr` function for run-time use. Is it even possible in C++14?

## Example

I want to use (probably extensively optimized)  `std::abs()` for run-time calls but, if possible, I want to use my own `constexpr` implementation of `abs()`.

---

I know that g++ already implements a lot of functions as `constexpr`, but I want clang++ compatibility as well. Not to mention, this is not limited to `abs`, I would possibly use it for other cases as well.

Comment: Do you want to know if some function is constexpr or not?

Comment: As I recal Johannes Schaub's trick was based on `noexcept` semantics. In the end I chose not to use that and just made the `constexpr` function not unreasonably inefficient (O(log n) stack usage, I saw no way to completely fix it). Note: **"clever" solutions are brittle**, generally.

Comment: The compiler will do its best to resolve at compile time, and the very same `constexpr` function will be compiled if needed. Do you want the compiler to tell you what it decided to do for a particular call? Or do you want to override the std::abs() call?

Comment: Here is another [trick](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24785fe2f3eb6798) (from [Filip Roséen - refp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1090079/filip-ros%C3%A9en-refp)):  [Determine `constexpr` execution - during compilation or at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683234/determine-constexpr-execution-during-compilation-or-at-runtime#comment45664014_28683234)