# C++ check if statement can be evaluated constexpr

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, constexpr, c++20, if-constexpr

Is there a method to decide whether something can be constexpr evaluated, and use the result as a constexpr boolean? My simplified use case is as follows:

```
template <typename base>
class derived
{
    template<size_t size>
    void do_stuff() { (...) }

    void do_stuff(size_t size) { (...) }
public:
    void execute()
    {
        if constexpr(is_constexpr(base::get_data())
        {
            do_stuff<base::get_data()>();
        }
        else
        {
            do_stuff(base::get_data());
        }
    }
}
```

My target is C++2a.

I found the following reddit thread, but I'm not a big fan of the macros. https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7c208c/is_constexpr_a_macro_that_check_if_an_expression/

Comment: Hmm, the body of a `if constexpr` will only be evaluated if the expression in the `if constexpr` is true at compile time. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: But what if the test in the if constexpr([test]) is not evaluatable at compile time?

Comment: Maybe you can do something with [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated)?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: If it's not evaluateable at compile time then what would you have the compiler do except error out or evaluate at run time?

Comment: If it can be evaluated at compile time, the first body should be executed. Else the second runtime body should be executed. I'm currently investigating 0x5453 's recommendation.

Comment: @AartStuurman: What is `do_stuff` that it can run at compile time or runtime, but itself should not be `constexpr`? Wouldn't it make more sense to just make it a `constexpr` function, and pass it the value of `get_data` as a parameter?

Comment: Meanwhile I've revised my design choice indeed, but I think this an interesting question nonetheless :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's another solution, which is more generic (applicable to any expression, without defining a separate template each time).

This solution leverages that (1) lambda expressions can be constexpr as of C++17 (2) the type of a captureless lambda is default constructible as of C++20.

The idea is, the overload that returns `true` is selected when and only when `Lambda{}()` can appear within a template argument, which effectively requires the lambda invocation to be a constant expression.

```
template<class Lambda, int=(Lambda{}(), 0)>
constexpr bool is_constexpr(Lambda) { return true; }
constexpr bool is_constexpr(...) { return false; }

template <typename base>
class derived
{
    // ...

    void execute()
    {
        if constexpr(is_constexpr([]{ base::get_data(); }))
            do_stuff<base::get_data()>();
        else
            do_stuff(base::get_data());
    }
}
```

Comment: Intriguing solution... this way you get the same result of my custom type traits but more synthetically and, above all, the exact expression verified (`base::get_data()`) is embedded in the argument and not hard-coded as in my solution. Very nice. I have to remember it.

Comment: I am accepting this, because it is an answer to the a generic case of the question. max66 answer is also very useful(in non-c++2a cases), but requires repetition for every usage :)

Comment: Comma operator SFINAE... my mind goes BOOM.

Comment: An enlightening solution to the problem. I have been doing some testing on this, and I believe that the use of the comma SFINAE is unneeded and I am pretty  sure that a template of the form `template<typename T, auto = T()() >`, where my `T` is your `Lambda` would equally suffice.

Comment: On second thoughts, the comma SFINE is needed due to void return type of lambda. (in my testing I was using a lambda akin to `[]{  base::get_data(); return true;}`, which is always non-void.

Answer (score 16):

Not exactly what you asked (I've developer a custom type trait specific for a `get_value()` static method... maybe it's possible to generalize it but, at the moment, I don't know how) but I suppose you can use SFINAE and make something as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto icee_helper (int)
   -> decltype( std::integral_constant<decltype(T::get_data()), T::get_data()>{},
                std::true_type{} );

template <typename>
constexpr auto icee_helper (long)
   -> std::false_type;

template <typename T>
using isConstExprEval = decltype(icee_helper<T>(0));

template <typename base>
struct derived
 {
   template <std::size_t I>
   void do_stuff()
    { std::cout << "constexpr case (" << I << ')' << std::endl; }

   void do_stuff (std::size_t i)
    { std::cout << "not constexpr case (" << i << ')' << std::endl; }

   void execute ()
    {
      if constexpr ( isConstExprEval<base>::value )
         do_stuff<base::get_data()>();
      else
         do_stuff(base::get_data());
    }
 };

struct foo
 { static constexpr std::size_t get_data () { return 1u; } };

struct bar
 { static std::size_t get_data () { return 2u; } };

int main ()
 { 
   derived<foo>{}.execute(); // print "constexpr case (1)"
   derived<bar>{}.execute(); // print "not constexpr case (2)"
 }
```

Comment: This is madness, this use of the comma operator, the long/int overload... Have an upvote. :/

Comment: @matovitch - never underestimate the power of the comma operator }:‑)

Comment: Will this work on platforms where `sizeof(long)` is equal to `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet - Yes. Because, for the language so for the compiler, they remain different types.

Answer (score 12):

```
template<auto> struct require_constant;
template<class T>
concept has_constexpr_data = requires { typename require_constant<T::get_data()>; };
```

This is basically what's used by [`std::ranges::split_view`](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.split.view).