# How to check whether some piece of code causes an error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20

Is there some standard function which takes a piece of code and checks whether it causes an error, returning true if the code is valid but false if the code is invalid?

For example:

```
int x;
bool a_bool = DoesItCauseAnError(constexpr auto y = x;); // Here a_bool is false, as "constexpr auto y = x;" would cause an error as x is not constexpr
```

This would be *immensely* useful and would save us all from all the pain of SFINAE and other weird hacks.

1. Is there a standard function which does this?
2. If not, why has it not been done already? It would be so useful and seems quite easy to implement.
3. If there isn't a standard function, has anybody done a plugin / static tool / compiler specific instruction (preferably gcc or clang) which can do this?

Comment: No, the closest you can come is to call the compiler to check the code for you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a shame. Any ideas about why none of the compilers do not support this?

Comment: Probably because your claim "*... and seems quite easy to implement*" isn't really true. You're basically asking for a compiler embedded inside a compiler that you can call programmatically. That's not going to be easy to do in general.

Comment: ... and the usefulness is questionable. I have never lacked this ability.

Comment: It won't "save us from SFINAE". Because *how* a condition is checked will not rid you of the need to discard invalid overloads.

Comment: consider adding a line `auto y = x;` after your call to `DoesItCauseAnError`, now you have `y` declared twice. Who is to blame for it? Is the error `auto y = x;` or is the error `constexpr auto y = x;` ? Also the possibility to nest such conditions would make it incredible complex I believe

Comment: Based on my understanding of compilers, the compiler would just parse the "constexpr auto y = x;" as if it was normal code, and if the line caused an error it would just replace DoesItCauseAnError(constexpr auto y = x;); by false. It wouldn't define any new variable

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some standard function which takes a piece of code and checks whether it causes an error, returning true if the code is valid but false if the code is invalid?

It is mathematically impossible to have such function (done at compile time). Read more about [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)!

In practice, errors do happen at runtime. A simple example is opening a file (e.g. some `std::ifstream` ...) which does not exist when your run your program.

Comment: OP is asking for errors that are apparent at compile time

Comment: Yes, and Rice's theorem proves that such a function cannot exist

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Comment: It is related to the Halting Problem. Ask your computer science professor

Comment: a compiler already does report code that needs to be reported according to the standard. Frankly, I believe you misunderstood the question. OP is merely asking to defer what can be done already at compile time to runtime

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818 What code does a compiler report?

Comment: `int x; constexpr  auto y = x;` is an error: https://godbolt.org/z/1KPfT4

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes I know that, the point of this question was to make decisions based on whether code was an error or not.

Comment: Umm, such a function doesn't need to test arbitrary semantic properties. Doing the work of a compiler is in no way a contradiction of Rice's Theorem. Or is GCC preforming a miracle when it bootstraps its own code?

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica Yes, I don't know why they're all saying it's impossible, the compiler would just need to report to me whether the line would cause an error or not... It already checks whether a line causes an error, so it should be fairly simple to implement this.

Comment: Such cases would be problematic
`template <int I> constexpr int Foo() { if constexpr (DoesItCauseAnError(Foo<I>())) { return 0; /*No error, whereas we claim there is an issue*/ } else { /*some error as missing return, array of size 0, ...*/ }
 }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the C++20 concepts: the `requires` keyword allows you to check at compile time if a type fulfill some conditions which would have failed otherwise.

For example, can I std::cout << something ?

```
using T = int;
if constexpr ( (requires(){std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<T>();}) )
    std::cout << "the tested type is displayable" << std::endl;
```

However I don't think you can verify the constexpr statement you provided as a block. But you can react to the constexpr property in the code:
[C++ check if statement can be evaluated constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288555/c-check-if-statement-can-be-evaluated-constexpr)