# C++ Is it possible to use a consistent syntax when passing a function pointer known at compile time vs runtime?

Tags: c++, function, syntax, delegates

I'm trying to wrap the call of a function into another function.
I can pass a function pointer or use a non type template parameter to call the function directly (through a constexpr function pointer).

```
using FunctionPtr = void(*)();

void foo(){}           // Function. Known at compile time
FunctionPtr bar = foo; // Function pointer. Set at runtime from a dll for example

// In C++ one may pass a function pointer as a value template
template<FunctionPtr function> void impl()
{
    function(); // (Optimal) Known at compile time
}

// Or pass at runtime
void impl(FunctionPtr function)
{
    function(); // Known at runtime. (*Might* be optimised or not)
}

int main()
{
    impl<foo>(); // Good. Compile time
    impl(foo);   // Bad. I should have called impl<foo>()
    impl(bar);   // Good. Runtime but syntax is different
    impl<bar>(); // Bad. Fails to compile

// Psudocode for desired result
    #define BIND(x) (is_function<decltype(x)> ? impl<x>() : impl(x))
    BIND(foo);
    BIND(bar);
    // This does not work with std::is_function_v() because of the compiler error when passing a function pointer in the impl<x>() case
}
```

My use case is for implementing 'Impossibly Fast Delegates'.
I would like them to handle both global functions and function pointers efficiently and seemlessly.

I have tried:

- template
- constexpr function pointers
- if constexpr()
- consteval
- if consteval() // c++23

This is compile time information, why are I forced to manually pick between <> and () ?
Is this a limitation of the language syntax?

Related: [C++ check if statement can be evaluated constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288555/c-check-if-statement-can-be-evaluated-constexpr)

Comment: You have some confusion when you write about "function value" vs "function pointer".  The non-type template parameter is also a function pointer.  I think you tripped yourself up by naming your function pointer typedef `Function` instead of say `FnPtr`.

Comment: This looks misguided. Passing a function into a template parameter makes sense when it's known at compile-time, that's the only condition. This choice shouldn't be affected by whether you have a function pointer or a reference, since the latter will be automatically converted to a pointer anyway. ...And not to mention that if the function body is visible (if you're willing to use templates, you obviously don't mind that), it's likely that the compiler will will inline things, and it wouldn't matter if you used a template parameter or not.

Comment: @Ben Voigt So in the impl<foo>() example, is the call to function() a call to a constexpr function pointer? That would make a lot of sense. Still, since the value is known at compile time this is effectily the same as calling the function directly which is what I mean by the "function value".

Your point still stands and I will update the question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm using this to implement impossibly fast delegates. If the function is known at compile time the wrapping function can call the correct function and inline etc, otherwise it'll have to store the function pointer using type erasure. 

I want a consistent syntax because I don't want my build to break if I change from using a function pointer loaded from a dll vs linking with a static library.

Comment: Did you check that passing a function pointer to a parameter (as opposed to a template parameter) doesn't get optimized to the same thing? It might.

Comment: Here's a tiny synthetic example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xf7qT8W67 Both ways of passing a function get inlined anyway. Maybe in your case it will be different, maybe not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have done. In your example the calls are optimised away and inlined which is good. However in the problem I'm working on (this is a simplified version) msvc does a poor job and there is a significant difference between the two wrapper functions.

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation I have discovered a solution.

The problem is that C++ lacks **pass by constexpr**.
That is why you're forced to use a template value for inconsistent syntax!
Passing a runtime value will fail to compile the value template.

You can however work around this by using a lambda which can return a constexpr value (C++17)

```
solution([&](){return foo;});
```

The second trick is to use **if constexpr()** which will discard the unused branch if it is not instansiated as part of a template.
The branch must therefore depend on the type of the lambda wrapper and be a constexpr statement.

Using a C++20 **requires** statement we can test if the substituion matches and better yet it get's ignored if it does not compile! Such as when we pass a runtime value to a compile time value template.

```
template<typename Lam> void solution(Lam lam)
{
    // Negative branch is discarded due to template dependency
    // Requires guards against the statement not compiling
    if constexpr(requires{foo<lam()>();})
    {
        impl<lam()>(); // Constexpr Value
    }
    else
    {
        impl(lam()); // Normal value
    }
}

#define BIND(x) ( solution([&](){return x;}) )
int main()
{
    // Consistent syntax and picks the best option
    BIND(foo);
    BIND(bar);

    Function fn = bar;
    BIND(fn);
}
```

[There is a proposal to add pass by constexpr to the language](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1045r1.html)

Comment: The `[&]` capture is both unnecessary and undesired.

Comment: That's not true. How else would I handle function pointers declared in the local scope? I've added a further use case to illustrate this point.

Comment: In that case you should probably capture a copy of the function pointer.