# accessing value of '"str"' through a 'const uint8_t {aka const unsigned char}' value in a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Assuming the following example

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint64_t XYZ(uint64_t c, size_t n, const uint8_t * d) noexcept {
    return (c & n) + (*d); // dummy. this is actually a crc64 function
}

template < size_t N > inline constexpr uint64_t ABC(const char(&a)[N]) noexcept {
    return XYZ(0, a[N-1] == '\0' ? (N-1) : N, reinterpret_cast< const uint8_t * >(a));
}

int main(void)
{
    constexpr uint64_t v = ABC("str");
    return (int)v; // dummy
}
```

MinGW GCC 6.3 seems to generate:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:13:31:   in constexpr expansion of 'ABC<4ull>("abc")'
main.cpp:8:15:   in constexpr expansion of 'XYZ(0ull, ((a[3ull] == 0) ? 3ull : 4ull), ((const uint8_t*)a))'
main.cpp:13:37: error: accessing value of '"abc"' through a 'const uint8_t {aka const unsigned char}' glvalue in a constant expression
     constexpr uint64_t v = ABC("abc");
                                     ^
```

If I remove the `constexpr` before `uint64_t v` it works. But I'm a bit confused as to why it doesn't when `constexpr` is present.

And also why is parameter `a` which is `char` seen as `uint8_t` aka. `unsigned char`.

Comment: Perhaps it is seeing it as a `uint8_t` because you are casting it as one?

Comment: Yes but I am using the parameter with the original type and not the one resulted from the cast.

Comment: [reinterpret_cast is not allowed in constexpr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24400015/1708801), it looks like clang points this out [see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qYc0gSkWyZPLH02Z)

Comment: Oh snap. Now it makes sense. Thanks @Shafik Yaghmour

Comment: the `inline` is btw redundant. `constexpr` expressions are implicitly inlined

Comment: Sorry, that was left over from me "playing" with the code.

Comment: "why is parameter a which is char seen as uint8_t aka. unsigned char."  - it isn't