# C++ constexpr does not work with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting, constexpr, memory-mapping

In older gcc versions (~6.X) the following code worked, 
however with newer version there are compile-errors.

```
struct test{
    constexpr static int* PORT1 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x12345678);
};
```

Compiler:

```
error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer
```

A C-like cast doesnt work either.

Note: Its for memory-maped-io, so i really want to read/write to a fixed address

Comment: reinterpret_cast [may not be used](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.15) in a constant expression.

Comment: so, there is no way to replace `#define PORT1 (int*)0x1` in C++