# constexpr pointer/reference initialization

Tags: c++, pointers, constexpr, constant-expression

I have an set of registers in MCU, and each of them has an unique adress. Imagine I have some register, that can be described with struct

```cpp
struct RegisterDefinition{
    u32 v1;
    u32 v2;
    u32 v3;
    u32 v4;
};
```

I know (from MCU reference manual), the adress that one of the registers of that type has in memory

```cpp
#define REGISTER_ADRESS 0x12345678
```

how can I `constexpr` initialize a pointer or reference of type `RegisterDefinition`, so I will be able to use that variable in constexpr constructors of other classes?

like

```cpp
inline constexpr somedef* registerPointer = reinterpret_cast<somedef*>(REGISTER_ADRESS);
```

Comment: You want `&v1 == REGISTER_ADRESS`?

Comment: `inline constexpr somedef* registerPointer = reinterpret_cast<somedef*>(REGISTER_ADRESS);`or  `inline constexpr somedef& registerRef = *reinterpret_cast<somedef*>(REGISTER_ADRESS);`

Comment: So you're asking how to workaround the ban on `reinterpret_cast` in constant expressions?

Comment: I guess, yes. It seems for my question to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376574/15879231

Answer (score 0):

This is currently impossible. The language does not permit it. `reinterpret_cast` is not permitted in constant expressions and there is no workaround.

Store the integral value of the address in a `constexpr` variable instead and use e.g. a function that returns a pointer from that integral value by `reinterpret_cast` as late as possible in whatever calculation you want to do at compile-time.